# Почему фоновое изображение не растягивает ячейку таблицы? Как растянуть?

Tags: html, css, background, img, table

Необходимо вставить изображение
[image: Изображение перфоратора]

в ячейку таблицы, чтобы получилось так [image: Необходимая картина]

А получается так [image: Фактическая картина]

ВНИМАНИЕ! Подбирать размер нельзя. Страница должна быть резиновой. Не обращайте внимание на отсутствие некоторых стилей и размеров в сравнении с целевым вариантом. Если добавлять таким образом `<td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIp8b.gif"></td>` получится белая полоса под картинкой. Её быть не должно. [image: Белая полоса под картинкой]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  border-top: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-right: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  border-left: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  border-right: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-left: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.one {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  color: #0000FF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.three {
  color: black;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.bord {
  border-top: 5px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-right: 5px solid #4D4D4D;
  border-left: 5px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4D4D4D;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="2">
  <tr align="center">
    <td class="one">От 6 до 20 мм</td>
    <td class="two">
      <div class="bord">Просверлим всё</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="center" class="three">ПЕРФОРАТОР</td>
    <td background="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIp8b.gif"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Я пробовал. Это не совсем то. При таком варианте образуется пустое пространство под изображением skr.sh/s5T4c3DmBr4?a Изначальное изображение не имеет этого и я честно говоря не пойму откуда берётся эта белая часть. В общем это не то.

Answer (score 0):

В css добавить
`img { display: block;}`
Изображение вставить между тегами td.
Решение уже было в англоязычной версии: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625949/there-is-always-a-little-space-under-images-inside-a-table